# How to resolve app crash issues in detox test?

Tags: android, testing, crash, emulation, detox

Description:

Detox Test Environment:

```
Detox version: 18.20.2
React Native version: 0.61.4
Node version: v10.16.3 (also tried 12.x - same results)
Device model: Pixel_API_26
OS: System Version: macOS 11.6.5 (20G527)
Test-runner (select one): jest
```

**detox configurations in package.json:**

```
"android.emu.debug": {
  "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug/app-dev-debug.apk",
  "build": "cd android; ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew --stacktrace assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug; cd ..",
  "type": "android.emulator",
  "name": "Pixel_API_26"
}
```

**Run detox build in GitHub pipeline:**

```
detox build --configuration android.emu.debug
```

Build is successful but it logs the following warnings, not sure these are the reasons for the following test failures.

```
Observed package id 'ndk;21.4.7075529' in inconsistent location '/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle' (Expected '/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529')
Observed package id 'platform-tools' in inconsistent location '/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools-2' (Expected '/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools')
Already observed package id 'platform-tools' in '/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools'. Skipping duplicate at '/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools-2'
```

**Run detox test in GitHub pipeline:**

```
detox test --configuration android.emu.debug --headless --cleanup --loglevel=trace
```

Expect to be successful, but app crashed with these error: (see details above)

```
detox\[4370\] TRACE: \[SESSION_JOINED\] app joined session 4fd6e783-15af-814c-ff90-4cf968dc2fd2
detox\[4370\] TRACE: \[WSS_SEND_TO, #tester\] {"type":"appConnected"}
detox\[4370\] TRACE: \[WS_MESSAGE\] {"type":"appConnected"}

detox\[4370\] TRACE: \[WS_SEND\] {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
detox\[4370\] TRACE: \[WSS_GET_FROM, #tester\] {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
detox\[4370\] TRACE: \[WSS_SEND_TO, #app\] {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}

detox\[4370\] TRACE: \[SESSION_TORN\] app exited session 4fd6e783-15af-814c-ff90-4cf968dc2fd2
detox\[4370\] TRACE: \[WSS_SEND_TO, #tester\] {"type":"appDisconnected"}
detox\[4370\] TRACE: \[WS_MESSAGE\] {"type":"appDisconnected"}
```

Comment: Please format question correctly so that it become easily understandable

Comment: Looks like an app crash in some hard-to-detect use case. Try to apply the `--record-logs all` arg to `detox test` and dig the crash up in `artifacts/device.log`